# Xamarin Forms speech recognition

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, speech-recognition

I want to create a mobile application with Xamarin Forms that will recognise speech and send commands to Esp32 board. Can anyone suggest good library/nuget for speech recognition?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Azure Speech Service to do the speech recognition work in your xamarin.form project. The official document shows the details about how to use it with the xamarin.forms.

For more information, you can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-cognitive-services/speech-recognition) and refer to the [official sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WebServices/CognitiveSpeechService).